# Amplify low voltage signal coming from lm35

Tags: operational-amplifier, lm35

I am using a lm35 to measure temperature from a box. The range of output voltage is 0.2V to 0.5V. I need to amplify this signal by 5. I tried using a non inverter op amp configuration with a LM358 and a lm381, but it seems this IC do not recognize this range of voltage, because at the output i get 0V.

Also, I cannot use negative supply and the maximum supply is 12V, so my range is 0-12V. I need to know which op amp to use.

Comment: Please post a schematic. You can start CircuitLab using the button on the editor toolbar and can edit your schematic, press "Save & Insert" and an editable schematic will be saved in your post. No account. No screengrab. No image uploads. No background grid.

Comment: LM358 should work fine. LM381 is totally inappropriate. Show us the circuit you tried with the LM358, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your anwers. I finally looked the lm324 and it is working fine.

The problem was that i am using the esp32 and its ADC does not behaves very well at low voltages. That is why i needed to amplify the lm35 output signal.

Comment: Jp, you didn't get any answers. You got comments. You can only use the "Your Answer" box for answers. It's not clear if your problem is solved or not. Add updates into your question, not as an answer. The [Tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) might help.